# Leaflet PDF page break overflow

Tags: python, printing, leaflet, overflow, pdfkit

I'm currently working on an automated report that includes leaflet maps.

The issue that I am facing is that when I place a map following a page break, I get overflow issues.

The issues are similar to those found [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1648)

Though none of the prosposed fixes helps me out. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposse you solved this, but if not, I found the solution.

In html, before you import leaflet.js add:

```
<script>L_DISABLE_3D = true;</script>
```

And works fine!

Comment: I did not find a solution for this issue, since i had to add multiple maps, and ran into load issues prior to PDF generation, so I opted to use a map to PNG solution instead. Thank you for your input though